# GridBagLayout location should be in another place?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have the following code

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=0;
    c.gridwidth=1;
    c.gridheight=1;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.insets= new Insets(2,2,2,2);
    this.add(pdfUrl,c);
    c.gridx=1;
    c.weightx=0.1;
    c.gridwidth=4;
    this.add(pdfUrlin,c);
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridwidth=1;
    c.gridy=1;
    c.weightx=0.0;
    this.add(pdfType);
```

This code produce this
[image: The code produces this]

I do not understand why the PDF Type is not on the line below. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small error, I think you meant to do: `this.add(pdfType, c);` instead of `this.add(pdfType);` =)

Comment: Oh god! Can't believe that one. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

You're not using the GridBagConstraints when adding the pdfType.  It shouldn't be

```
this.add(pdfType);
```

but rather

```
add(pdfType, c); // also no need for "this"
```